# How to redirect or show a page rather than "Forbidden" when i have directory listings off (htaccess/unix)

Tags: php, apache, unix, .htaccess

I've set it in htaccess so it won't display the contents of directories, rather it will just show the usual Forbidden page.

how can i either:

show a certain page
or
redirect to a certain page

rather than just this default "Forbidden" page?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument) directive of Apache to display a custom error document.

The appropriate error code for Forbidden is 403.

Comment: Nice to see a link to Apache documentation. Most users don't even think it exists ;-)