# Redirect if no index.php rather than showing directory listing

Tags: php, .htaccess

Currently, when you visit my website's sub folders, it shows the directory listing.  That's really scary since it contains php classes with sensitive information.  Now I was successful in turing off the directory listing by using "IndexIgnore *" in my root .htaccess file.  That partially works by showing a blank directory listing.  However, I would like to be able to do one of the following two if it is possible:

1. Redirect to a folder above, and if that folder doesn't contain an index.php either, go up another level.  Handy for folders such as http://www.duaworld.com/resources/images/about
2. If that's not possible, simply redirect to the root of the site

I had a look at the following question but that only works if there is a 403 error message.  In my case, it shows a blank directory, no error.

[How to redirect or show a page rather than "Forbidden" when i have directory listings off (htaccess/unix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515045/how-to-redirect-or-show-a-page-rather-than-forbidden-when-i-have-directory-lis)

Thanks alot for the help guys.

Comment: Disabling directory listings is usually done with `Options -Indexes`; this will trigger a `403 Forbidden` instead of a blank page.

Comment: SIdenote:unless your php classes doesn't echo out the sensitive information, they're not gonna be read by any user. If you open a php page you don't see the sourcecode. Agree with the indexing of directories, though. But why do you want a redirect? why not a "forbidden" error, or a blank page, as usually happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be this is probably [best solution](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html) for you request

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all, check [Apache `Options` documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options), especially:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Than you have several options, what to do, for example:

#### "Zend way"

is to have directories like this:

- `public/` here goes just `index.php` and css, js, images...
- `library/` here goes all the application

And set:

```
DocumentRoot .../public/
```

so private content will **NEVER** be displayed in browser

#### Deny from

again you have structure like this:

- `public_html` - hosting root for your web, `index.php` goes here
- `public_html/library` - private library

If you have `DocumentRoot .../public_html`, than you may create `.htaccess` file like this:

```
Allow from none
Deny from all
Order allow,deny
```

#### "PhpBB way"

<sub>At least I remember it as a part of phpBB</sub>

Create `index.html` (or `index.php` or both) with context like this one:

```
<h1>Hacker attempt!</h1>
```

#### Conclusion

I'd definitely go with "Zend way" (even if you're in control of your webserver you may accidentally allow `Indexes`).

If you cannot (for example bad hosting configuration or you're not using dependency injection and include files manually) and you have to have sensitive data in public directory (ab)user also may always guess file name correctly so you should add something like this to each sensitive file (php):

```
if( !defined( 'IN_APPLICATION')){
    die('Hacker attempt!');
}
```

Also use mentioned `.htaccess` with `Deny from all` and just to prevent misconfiguration add `index.html` to every directory.

If you need to keep private files in public html directory just because you have many fixed paths in your app (it's poor design) you may do symlink:

```
.../public_html/library -> .../private
```

And add:

```
Options -FollowSymlinks
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways... one of them would be using .htaccess or if you want it from PHP just create **`index.php`** script like this

```
<?php header('Location: ../'); ?>
```

and put it into every (sub)directory other than root.

That will redirect all directory-requests to homepage (actually to upper-level directory).

(I don't use this solution any more, but before I found .htaccess I was doing that this way)